# AWS Amplify ci/cd hangs at test stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, jestjs, continuous-integration, aws-amplify

I have my amplify project connected to gitlab
And added this segment to run API Jest tests:

```
test:
  phases:
    preTest:
      commands:
       - npm install
    test:
      commands:
        - npm test
```

But the test section became and stays as "pending"

In logs I see only the following:

```
                                 # Starting phase: preTest
                                 # Executing command: npm install
2020-10-28T05:58:39.496Z [WARNING]: npm
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running test in watch mode solved the problem:

```
npm test -- --watchAll=false
```